# ASN.1 define that octetstring/bitstring is constructed

Tags: asn.1

I have looked through many links but didn't find how to identify that octetstring/bitstring is constructed.  I parse it as TLV and V contains value of octetstring/bitstring.  Is there bit in V which is responsible for it as it is in tag?

Comment: I'm wondering if you have access to the schema? If so then you can get an ASN.1 compiler to write all your encoders / decoders for you in a variety of different languages. That's much quicker and easier than hand crafting code to talk BER / DER / etc. If it's BER encoded data then you can plug that into an ASN.1 viewer http://www.obj-sys.com/products/asn1ve/index.php and it will tell you what the schema might look like

Comment: I'm not sure if schema will help. There are cases in PKIX profile where constructed forms of `OCTET_STRING` and `BIT_STRING` are used without specifying the nested data type, because it is VARIANT (I suspect).

Comment: @CryptoGuy, well, the schema ought to help, if nothing else saying what the PDU should have looked like, possibly? - Scrub that, just caught up with your chat with pepo!

Answer (score 4):

According to [ITU-T X.690](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690-201508-I) this is defined for BER:

> The encoding of an octetstring value shall be either primitive or constructed at the option of the sender.

DER restricts the encoding to primitive only. The same applies for bitstring.

To encode ASN.1 object as constructed you need to set bit 6 of TAG octet in TLV to 1 as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#Encoding). The whole TAG element should be binary 00 (<-tag class universal) 1 (constructed) 00100 (<-tag number) = 00100100 = 24 hex = 36 dec.

Bitstring will be similar - in binary 00100011 = 23 hex = 35 dec.

**EDIT:**

after a long discussion with @CryptoGuy I realized that I didn't answer your question correctly. There is no bit in Value that would say anything about a structure. If you know that the object you are parsing contains Octet string with structure encoded in the Value then you implement your application accordingly.

If you do not know the object you are parsing then you will have to try and parse any type that can be constructed i.e. sequence, set, octet string, etc.
There is no other way to do it as far as I know.

Comment: It is incorrect in a given case. Constructed forms of `OCTET_STRING` and `BIT_STRING` types use primitive encoding: `0x03` for `BIT_STRING` and `0x04` for `OCTET_STRING`.

Comment: @CryptoGuy I don't think so. If you take i.e. sequence which is a constructed type by definition you get 00110000 binary. Bit 6 is set to 1 because it is constructed and bits 5 to 1 have the value of 10000 (10 hex). Could you prove that TAG octet is encoded differently for seqence and octet string?

Comment: I can prove, but comment form doesn't support images or formatted code, unfortunately.

Comment: @CryptoGuy Section 8.6.4.2 in [ITU-T X.690](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690-201508-I). It is an example of bitstring encoding in primitive and constructed form.

Comment: I don't remember right now, but there was additional document that explains this. Two images for you: https://www.sysadmins.lv/content/images/trash/bit_string.png and https://www.sysadmins.lv/content/images/trash/octet_string.png.

Comment: @CryptoGuy Yes I know that i.e. ASN.1 editor goes deeper and looks for asn.1 objects in value of octet string. But try to parse `04 04 03 02 05 A0` (octet string contains bit string - part of keyUsage) and `04 14 6A 43 90 7D 3B 98 14 72 52 95 3A AA 28 0A 43 F8 51 7E D3 A6` (it is a part of subjectKeyIdentifier and does not contain any asn.1 objects). Can you explain why it is encoded the same even when one is constructed (in your sense) and the other is not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120633/discussion-between-cryptoguy-and-pepo).

Comment: Thanks a million for your discussion and real help for me!

Comment: In the Distinguished Encoding Rules (X.690 10.2) it says that the constructed form is not allowed.

Comment: @Mats Thanks, I have missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The primitive/contructed bit is a property of the Basic Encoding Rules and not of the ASN.1 item. So an octetstring/bitstring does not have this property.

It represents how the Value is encoded. Either primitive as raw data or constructed as a list of TLV items that combine to the actual data.

If you can restrict the input to using Distinguished Encoding Rules, it only allows the primitive form for octectstring/bitstring.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explanation. Could you kindly help me with BER decoding of octetstring/bitstring if it is constructed?

Comment: In order to decode an octet string that has been encoded in BER in constructed form, you should only need to know what it means for an octet string to be encoded in constructed form.  Refer to section 8.7 of X.690.  I think it is pretty clear.  I suggest you ask a new question if you don't understand something in that section, after you have read it.